# How to get a cell value or row value in ControlGrid Level 1 GridView C# - DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

i wonder if how can i get the value of the cell in `ControlGrid` Level 1 `GridView`.

i had already tried the click event with this code

```
 private void gvPrerequisit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox(gvPrerequisit.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ProspectusPrequisitID").ToString());
    }
```

but on debugging mode this message appear.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Here's the screenshot on the control grid.
[image]

Then the cell to get the value.
[image]

Anyone can help? thanks.

Comment: you know there are several working examples on how to get this ..have you done a simple google search..?

Comment: @MethodMan i have google it almost 5x but i don't get the solution.

Comment: what are you typing in the google search I just did a google search and it had numerous examples

Comment: same as my title on this question maybe my keywords did not fit on my question, Getting focused row from Master-Detail GridControl hmm idk. how about you?

Comment: hmmm i think i got it, just shortcut code..

`GridView gv = (GridView)gvProsSubjects.GetDetailView(gvProsSubjects.FocusedRowHandle, 0);
            MessageBox.Show(gv.GetFocusedRowCellValue("SubjectCode").ToString());`

work fine.

Comment: that's good.. glad you were able to figure this out..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69417/discussion-between-mardagz-and-methodman).

Comment: I dont know why this question is downvoted, most available articles on the Internet only cover main level grid rows and not detail rows illustrated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to cast the GridView

On click event GridView1

```
GridView gv = (GridView)GridView1.GetDetailView(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, 0);
```

so this `gv` is now your GridView2

then you can call the value by this...

```
gv.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ColumnName"))
```